Why did Martin Luther adopt and promote the then-novel Historicist View of Revelation yet reject Revelation as an inspired text?
Luther seems to have been convinced of the then-novel historicist view of Revelation because it made sense to him the Antichrist figure was the then-installed Pope. At the same time, he did not recognize his/Paul's Jesus in the Revelation and said "I can in no way detect that the Holy Spirit produced it." He even put Revelation at the end of his "The Bible" to indicate that it was the text in which he had the least confidence. Does Luther ever explain his apparent inconsistency in his regard for the value of what was written in Revelation?
My question is based on the history provided by Dr. Bruce Gore in this video.
This question seems appropriate to ask since Luther's estimation of the Pope as THE Antichrist was the largely the impetus of Protestantism and the horrific Thirty Years War. Since this accusation, the once unquestioned Catholic Church became a pariah to a great deal of Protestantism. "A Mighty Fortress Is Our God," arguably Luther's most famous hymn was also arguably a battle hymn against the Papacy:

LYRICS:
1 A mighty fortress is our God,
a bulwark never failing;
our helper he, amid the flood
of mortal ills prevailing.
For still our ancient foe
does seek to work us woe;
his craft and power are great,
and armed with cruel hate,
on earth is not his equal.


2 Did we in our own strength confide,
our striving would be losing,
were not the right Man on our side,
the Man of God's own choosing.
You ask who that may be?
Christ Jesus, it is he;
Lord Sabaoth his name,
from age to age the same;
and he must win the battle.


3 And though this world, with devils filled,
should threaten to undo us,
we will not fear, for God has willed
his truth to triumph through us.
The prince of darkness grim,
we tremble not for him;
his rage we can endure,
for lo! his doom is sure;
one little word shall fell him.


4 That Word above all earthly powers
no thanks to them abideth;
the Spirit and the gifts are ours
through him who with us sideth.
Let goods and kindred go,
this mortal life also;
the body they may kill:
God's truth abideth still;
his kingdom is forever!

How does Luther explain this momentous accusation without contradicting himself about Revelation?

(1) Where does the "ravings of a madman" quote come from? (2) Of course, the Antichrist motif doesn't depend on Revelation alone.

The question has not substantiated its claim. See Martin Luther's Preface to Revelation.

I removed the reference to "ravings of a madman."

You did not remove the claim from your header question.

Done, thanks...

Re Luther's hymn "A Mighty Fortress is our God": Rather than being a battle hymn against the Papacy, the hymn was based on Psalm 46. The Mighty Fortress is a metaphor to describe God as our defence. He is mighty to guard, protect, and keep his people safe. The “ancient foe” is Satan, the devil, the Prince of Darkness.  The Man of God who is on our side is Christ Jesus, the “Lord of Hosts.” No mention of Popes. Is the focus of your question on Luther's view that the book of Revelation was not divinely inspired by the Holy Spirit, or is it on claims that the Pope was the Antichrist?

I find it puzzling that Luther adopted the historicist view of Revelation (which split the Catholic Church) when he held Revelation to not be inspired.

Apparently, Luther did have an issue with Revelation at first, but later rewrote his introduction to Revelation with support.

this [old/previous] preface to Revelation was included in his translation of the New Testament between 1522 to 1527, but was then rewritten in 1530, and subsequent editions of Luther's Bible use the 1530 rewrite. The rewrite is hardly ever referred to within anti-Luther polemics. John Warwick Montgomery points out,
Luther’s short and extremely negative Preface to the Revelation of St. John was completely dropped after 1522, and the Reformer replaced it with a long and entirely commendatory Preface (1530). Because “some of the ancient fathers held the opinion that it was not the work of St. John the apostle,” Luther leaves the authorship question open, but asserts that he can no longer “let the book alone,” for “we see, in this book, that through and above all plagues and beasts and evil angels Christ is with His saints, and wins the victory at last.” In his original, 1532 Preface to Ezekiel, Luther made a cross-reference to the Revelation of St. John with no hint of criticism; in his later, much fuller Preface to Ezekiel, he concludes on the note that if one wishes to go into prophetic study, more deeply, “the Revelation of John can also help.” [John Warwick Montgomery, “Lessons From Luther On The Inerrancy Of Holy Writ’s,” Westminster Theological Journal Volume 36, 295.] -source-

By failing to include Luther's update about Revelation, it simply needs to be mentioned.
To answer the OP, apparently God changed Luther's mind to conclude Revelation is inspired text and should be part of NT Canon.  There is no contradiction as the OP assumes.

Well done for posting Luther's update on Revelation.

Why did Martin Luther adopt and promote the then-novel Historicist View of Revelation yet reject Revelation as an inspired text?
[1] Historicist interpretations on the Book of Revelation, and the view that the Pope was the Antichrist, had been levelled at various popes throughout the centuries. Even as far back as Jerome, a critical finger had been appointed at the papacy.

In calling the pope the "Antichrist", the early Lutherans stood in a tradition that reached back into the eleventh century. Not only dissidents and heretics but even saints had called the bishop of Rome the "Antichrist" when they wished to castigate his abuse of power. What Lutherans understood as a papal claim to unlimited authority over everything and everyone reminded them of the apocalyptic imagery of Daniel 11, a passage that even prior to the Reformation had been applied to the pope as the Antichrist of the last days.

The identification of the Pope with the Antichrist was so ingrained in the Reformation Era, that Luther himself stated it repeatedly:

"This teaching [of the supremacy of the pope] shows forcefully that the Pope is the very Antichrist, who has exalted himself above, and opposed himself against Christ, because he will not permit Christians to be saved without his power, which, nevertheless, is nothing, and is neither ordained nor commanded by God".

The historicist interpretation of the Book of Revelation “took off” during the 16th century then Futurism and Preterism were derived from Jesuit writings, whose counter-reformation efforts were aimed at opposing this interpretation that the Antichrist was the Papacy or the power of the Roman Catholic Church.  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historicist_interpretations_of_the_Book_of_Revelation
[2] How does Luther explain this momentous accusation without contradicting himself about Revelation? As far as accusing the Pope of being the Antichrist, Luther is guilty as charged. However, I don’t think “the Antichrist” is actually mentioned in the Book of Revelation, although John writes about that subject in his first and second epistles. That being the case, perhaps there is no contradiction in calling the Pope the Antichrist, whilst questioning the divine inspiration of the Holy Spirit in the writing of the Revelation of Christ Jesus that John was given in his later years.
Luther said this in his 1522 preface:

Many of the fathers also rejected this book a long time ago; although St. Jerome, to be sure, refers to it in exalted terms and says that it is above all praise and that there are as many mysteries in it as words. Still, Jerome cannot prove this at all, and his praise at numerous places is too generous.

Perhaps the real problem Luther had with Revelation was that he simply didn’t understand it.  He said this:

Moreover he [John] seems to me to be going much too far when he commends his own book so highly [Revelation 22]—indeed, more than any of the other sacred books do, though they are much more important—and threatens that if anyone takes away anything from it, God will take away from him, etc. Again, they are supposed to be blessed who keep what is written in this book; and yet no one knows what that is, to say nothing of keeping it. This is just the same as if we did not have the book at all. And there are many far better books available for us to keep.

Luther simply preferred to “stick to the books which present Christ to me clearly and purely.”
Even today, the visions granted to John regarding Christ Jesus and the events leading up to the last days and the second coming are seldom studied or understood by Christians.  I don’t see any contradiction in Luther’s opinion of the Revelation and the historicist view of the Antichrist.  Luther was not alone.  Anyway, our eternal salvation does not depend on who we think the Antichrist will turn out to be, only that we belong to Christ Jesus and place our faith in Him.

Thank you for this excellent research. I'm starting to see that Luther's view of the Popes as Antichrist probably arose from Thessalonians, and he was taken by historicism because it best fit with his notion of the Popes as Antichrists. Makes sense.

Just up-voted SLM's answer giving Luther's updated comments on Revelation.
